# Creating webapps in Azure using AZ cli command

Tags: azure, azure-cli

```
   While creating webapps using Az cli in Azure, the command line have no option to mention the location parameter. However while creating from azure portal,there is a option where in we can select the region .
```

Following is the link to the command and the command itsel
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest

```
az webapp create --name
                 --plan
                 --resource-group
                 [--assign-identity]
                 [--deployment-container-image-name]
                 [--deployment-local-git]
                 [--deployment-source-branch]
                 [--deployment-source-url]
                 [--docker-registry-server-password]
                 [--docker-registry-server-user]
                 [--https-only {false, true}]
                 [--multicontainer-config-file]
                 [--multicontainer-config-type {COMPOSE, KUBE}]
                 [--role]
                 [--runtime]
                 [--scope]
                 [--startup-file]
                 [--subnet]
                 [--tags]
                 [--vnet]
```

Comment: What is happening if you create the webapp with Azure CLI without the missing location?

Comment: @user19203752 - we don't have any parameter to specify location while creating the web app using the Azure CLI cmdlet `Az webapp create`. Try using `New-Azwebapp` [PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebapp?view=azps-8.0.0) if you want to specify the location while creating the webapp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`az webapp up`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up) CLI command which has a `location` switch like

```
az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName --runtime "java:11:Java SE:11" -l locationName
```

BTW, if you even don't specify the location while using `az webapp create` it will be default to the region of "Resource Group" or if you are specifying app service plan then that region would be in use